# error mozilla? php

Tags: php

buenas tardes me surgio un problema con mi navegador mozilla,intente abrir un archivo php en el navegador, este archivo lo habia probado antes y funcionaba lo mas bien, no le hice ningun cambio en el codigo pero al cabo de unos dias al volver abrir el mismo archivo me surgio un error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aparece parte del codigo, todo el codigo esta bien escrito y cerrado

```
<?php

$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','phpmysql','3308');

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "<h3>no se pudo conectar</h3> ".mysqli_connect_error();
}else{
    echo "<h3>conexion exitosa capo</h3>";
}
//para setear codificacion de caracteres
mysqli_query($conexion,"SET NAMES'utf8'");

//Consulta select desde php

$notas = mysqli_query($conexion,'SELECT * FROM notas');

var_dump($notas);

?>
```

todo esta bien cerrado pero mozilla da a entender como si deja alguna sentencia sin cerrar, y no es unicamente estetico el problema, ya que no me deja usar el var_dump para corroborar el contenido de la variable, me fije en la consola de desarrollador de mozilla y aparecia asi no se porque en inspector si se fijan el navegador comenta el codigo sin razon aparente, como arreglo este error, desde ya muchas gracias, perdon porque escribir mucho!!.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: PHP necesita un servidor para ejecutarse, ya se XAMPP o Wamp tu lo estas ejecutando directamente en el navegador por eso no te funciona, tienes como opción instalar [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/es/index.html)

En la URL de tu imagen dice Wamp, tiene que iniciar el servidor y ejecutarlo desde localhost/{ruta donde tenga el proyecto}

Comment: Los navegadores web solo interpretan HTML, CSS y JS dicho lo anterior debes seguir la recomendación del comentario anterior

Comment: Ya tienes instalado _Wampserver_ y deberías abrir la página desde `http://localhost/php+mysql/index2-0.php` en lugar de su ubicación en el disco duro.

Comment: sisis muchas gracias la verdad me habia olvidado de abrir desde localhost, gracias a lo que se tomaron su tiempo de responder